# Countdown timer that refreshes depending on the data I receive by a WebSocket

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I want to build a 10-seconds JQuery Countdown-Timer with **a WebSocket that refreshes every second**. It should reset the timer at x seconds (depending on the data I get from the WebSocket). If I get data for a specific timer, it should start over and counting down from 10s again, but only **for this specific timer**. 
If one of these timers drops to 0, the countdown should stop completely.

At the moment I use setInterval for demonstration reasons, but I want to implement this timers to the WebSocket as mentioned: http://jsfiddle.net/alexiovay/azkdry0w/5/

JavaScript:

```
var setup = function(){
  $('.count').each(eachSetup);    
};

var eachSetup = function(){
  var count = $(this);
  var sec = count.data('seconds') ;  
  count.data('count', sec);
};

var everySecond = function(){  
  $('.count').each(eachCount);    
};

var eachCount = function(){
  var count = $(this);
  var s = count.data('count');
  count.text(s);
  s--;
  if(s < 0) { 
    s = 0;
  }
  count.data('count', s);
};

setup();
setInterval(everySecond, 1000);
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="count" data-seconds="5"></p>
<p class="count" data-seconds="10"></p>
<p class="count" data-seconds="15"></p>
```

My WebSocket starts like this and refreshes every second:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');   
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
    $.each(data.rows,function(index,row){   
...
```

Comment: Can you post some more related code here?

Comment: Check the JSFiddle link please @Mouser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting, say, *data.user* and *data.seconds* from the socket, you could do the following:

```js
var timers = []; // Creates an array to store your timers
socket.on('notification', function(data) { // Listen for 'notification' from socket
    if(timers.length > 0) {
        for(i in timers) {
            if(timers[i][0] === data.timer) {
                timers[i][1] = 10; // If timer for data.user already exists, set it to 10 seconds again.
            } else {
                timers.push([data.timer, data.seconds]); // Else, create it with data.seconds seconds
            }
        }
    } else {
        timers.push([data.timer, data.seconds]);
    }
}

function timerCount() {
    for(i in timers) {
        if(timers[i][1] <= 0) {
            delete timers[i]; // If timer seconds is less than 0, delete it.
        } else {
            timers[i][1]--; // Else, decrease it by 1 second.
        }
    }
}

setInterval(timerCount, 1000); // Runs the timerCount() function every second.
```

Comment: I'll test it now. But is `timerCount` supposed to be outside the socket function?

Comment: In this case, timerCount is a function that will run every second, it's independent from the socket. It'll check for items in the timers array, and update them accordingly. The socket function just updates the timers array with the new info (i.e new user, reset timer to 10s, etc.) - So, yes, it is supposed to be outside the socket function.

Comment: This is my relevant code now: http://pastebin.com/g3iGvzTY The console doesn't show any results. Also I don't know about this concept, because wouldn't there be a for loop every second? Isn't there another way saving more resources? Because I don't want to create timers every second. As you see in the code it's about an auction house. And if there is a new price (new bid), the countdown should reset to 10 seconds. If not, it just should keep on counting down to 10. But shouldn't dissapear or get deleted.

Comment: I don't see any code there that would show any results in the console, and yes, it would run a for loop every second, but still it should be way more efficient than having an independent timer for each user, and as far as I can think, this is the best way to update all their timers in efficiently. Also, yes, I just noticed, the last line should be `setInterval(timerCount, 1000);` instead of `setTimeout(timerCount, 1000);`, my bad.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "for each user"? This confuses me. It's about an auction house website. And if the price changes (line 18 @ http://pastebin.com/g3iGvzTY), the timer should be reset to 10. The code to show me results is at line 36 (console.log), but I don't get any results. Thank you, if you could take a look again.

Comment: Sorry, by "each user" I meant to say "each timer", please check the updated answer. I fixed the cause of the code not giving you any results.

Comment: You weren't getting any results because I forgot to check first if the timers array has more than 0 elements, before running the for loop. Now it should work, check the updated answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: I think it's nearly perfect, but he only creates one timer as it seems. I activated two auctions now, but console.log only outputs one timer for the first auction. My Code now: http://pastebin.com/d6xcn9v9

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at it when I get back home. Shouldn't take more than 2hrs

Comment: Also, feel free to edit the answer with your fix for it. It may help someone else as well :)

Comment: I will do that. But I think the code isn't perfect yet. How can I avoid that the array will be created every second if it already exists? This is the code now: http://pastebin.com/0w93D4mt

Comment: The array is only created once, what the function does every second is check for its content and update it accordingly, so it should just 'edit' it, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: That is, unless you changed the code and the part that re-creates it is not in that Pastebin.